# Extrair dados de um QR Code após leitura

Tags: android, qrcode

Tenho um app na Play Store desenvolvido para uma ONG sem fins lucrativos, onde é doado cupons fiscais e armazenado em uma planilha do Excel cada registro, onde contém:

- CNPJ
- Data da Compra
- COO
- Valor da Nota

Com o QR Code sendo uma tendência para esses cupons também, preciso de ajuda para fazer com que meu aplicativo extraia essas informações ao ler o QR Code.

No aplicativo há um botão que habilita o QR Code, onde ele executa o Barcode Scanner. Atualmente meu código está assim:

```
// Botão para abrir câmera e usar o QR Code (Irá abrir a Store para baixar um app nativo)
    btnQR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnQR);
    btnQR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
            integrator.addExtra("SCAN_WIDTH", 640);
            integrator.addExtra("SCAN_WEIGHT", 480);
            integrator.addExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE,PRODUCT_MODE");
            integrator.addExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Escaneie o QR Code");
            integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
        }
    });
```

O código acima habilita o leitor.

Preciso de ajuda nessa parte em diante. Estou com o manual aberto e vi que dentro do QR Code há também Hash QR Code, e que as informações são criptografadas em SHA-1, e deve ser em HEXADECIMAL.

Meu caso seria ler essa codificação, e descodificar, fazendo com que as informações que eu preciso (descrito no começo) preencha automaticamente.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Talvez a documentação ajude.Penso que fica no result. https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.html